# Can we have an option to disable the "don't forget to accept" reminder?

Tags: feature-request, voting, accepted-answer, popups

The biggest peeve is sometimes I vote up an answer mid-way through reading it, and the "don't forget to accept" message blocks the remaining text, so I scramble and triple-click it until it closes.

Anyways I frequently scan my question list and search for SO's reminders, ("Consider accepting an answer") so the "don't forget to accept" is wholly unnecessary to some, and there should be a way to disable it. Do you think so too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It goes away after 1 month automatically. Just wait.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much. Very smart site.

Comment: A month after being posted? A month after the last comment/answer? A month without a view?

Comment: I have my Yearling badge, and still get this message every day.

Comment: In a more recent question, Jeff has said it expires in 60 days.

Comment: Hey this is really unspecific, could you please clarify?

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't bother me, really. I think it's an important feature to make sure people accept answers to questions that have been answered, and I don't particularly see a *need* for being able to disable it. If it becomes to easy to dismiss it might as well not exist, since no one would read it.