# How else can I remove the "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" note without accepting a correct answer?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, user-interface, profile-page

After a couple of weeks of not having "one correct answer" on questions where several answers are correct on their own rights, I decided to mark the questions as a wiki. I think I did this after the accepted answer percentage appeared on the profiles. And wikis often don't have "one correct answer". And I have several of those questions that I marked as wiki, which AFAIK cannot be undone). It's somewhat annoying that I have those red notes in the list that doesn't serve any purpose. And again, red often mean there's an error of some sort.

**Edit**: The note also disappears when a question is closed.

How else can I remove "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" without accepting a correct answer?

Also, would it be good to let them implement that questions marked as wiki to not have that message?

Comment: Seems this is a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-dont-forget-to-accept-reminder/14599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This message will expire in one month.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-dont-forget-to-accept-reminder/14599#14599)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't gotten an answer that meets your needs, or there isn't a correct one in the bunch, just ignore it. The line is just a reminder, a gentle prod.

Comment: But it's in RED.  That's an error to most humans that I know.

Comment: Run the red light, drink the red cordial. Red is a flag, a warning, a stop, yes. But a lot of people still just ignore it or even use it as a pause to think and look over something.