# Why have all the "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" reminders disappeared in my list of questions?

Tags: support, bounties, accepted-answer

I remember seeing red messages like these when I look at my list of questions:

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

But I have not seen these (annoying) reminders recently. Did I gain a new privilege that would explain why I no longer see these red reminders when I look at my list of questions?

Comment: Is this on one specific SE site, or every site in the network?

Comment: @F1Krazy I've only noticed it on https://money.stackexchange.com. Could it be that I've crossed 5k in reputation points?

Comment: There are a two reasons these stop appearing I know of, If the question is closed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18031/how-else-can-i-remove-the-have-you-considered-accepting-an-answer-or-starting-a or if a month passes since asking https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14599/300925 Do these apply to your questions?

Comment: You stop seeing these reminders when you gain the privilege to cast close votes: [When is the message "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" displayed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214877/when-is-the-message-have-you-considered-accepting-an-answer-or-starting-a-bount)