# Does the *Remember to accept this answer* popup really need to come up for experienced users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, popups

I have accounts that I use infrequently on various other SE sites, and I noticed today that I am still getting "Remember to accept this answer if it helped you" popups (after upvoting an answer), even though I am clearly an experienced user on SO and a few other sites, and I have even accepted an answer before on the site in question (electronics.SE).

Could this popup be stopped based on network reputation or a similar metric? I know it is a bit pedantic of me, but it does get annoying.

Additionally, what is the user requirement for that popup to go away? I don't think I get it here.

Comment: "I don't think I get it here." 100% accept rate here, there's nothing to nag you about. (I don't know the threshold though.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-dont-forget-to-accept-reminder though it doesn't suggest specific solution.

Comment: On Electronics SE, you're not an experienced user, and each site is sort of developed as a separate site, even though they all share the same engine. To try and separate all the common features from the individual site features might be a little more bloat than needed. These popups don't bother me. I just quickly click on them to make them go away.

Comment: The specific solution would be to not nag if the user received an association bonus, but is the message really that annoying?

Comment: no, not really annoying. just thought it probably shouldn't be there. Maybe it's more of a bug than anything.